# Facebook Messenger notification sound for contact seems to not be in use

Tags: notifications, contacts, facebook-messenger

I want to set the notification sound for messages from a Facebook Messenger contact.

When showing the contact profile, there is a "Notification Sounds" menu
and when clicking that, I can select a sound.

[image: Contact profile]

[image: Notification sounds]

However, the system default sound will still play when I receive a message from the contact as if the setting was not in use.

Why?

Comment: I don't use Facebook Messenger, but based on similar messaging apps: after selecting a custom notification, does it show on the App info's Notifications?